# Loading MarkerClusters while the bounding boxs changes position and display

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

im using leaflet markerClusters and javascript to develop a map where i want to generate clusters according to the screen bounds.
I have a service that returns me a list of points depending on screen bounds, with lat and lng properties.

Declaration of variables map and cluster.

```
/* Single marker cluster layer to hold all clusters */

var markers = L.markerClusterGroup({
  spiderLegPolylineOptions: {weight: 0},
  clockHelpingCircleOptions: {weight: .7, opacity: 1, color: 'black', fillOpacity: 0, dashArray: '10 5'},

  elementsPlacementStrategy: 'spiral',
  helpingCircles: true,

  spiderfyDistanceSurplus: 25,
  spiderfyDistanceMultiplier: 1,

  elementsMultiplier: 1.4,
  firstCircleElements: 8

});

for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  var circle = L.circleMarker([Math.random() * 30, Math.random() * 30], {fillOpacity: 0.7, radius: 8, fillColor: 'red',
  color: 'black'});
  markers.addLayer(circle);
}


var sudOest = L.latLng(41.512742, 2.410589);
var nordEst = L.latLng(41.590395, 2.489678);


map = L.map("map", {
    zoom: 14,
    crs: crs25831,
    layers: [baseLayers[Object.keys(baseLayers)[0]]],
    zoomControl: false,
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 6,
    maxBounds: L.latLngBounds(sudOest, nordEst)
}).setView([40.705008, -73.995581],6);


map.addLayer(markers);
```

Function called on move where load all coordinates points according to the bounding box

```
function loadPoints(zoomActual){
    for (var prop in capesDinamiques) {  
      if(map.getZoom()>3){  
        if(capesDinamiques[prop][0]){

        removeAreaLayer(prop); //clean the other markercluster

        baseLayers[prop] =afegirCapaServeiWeb(capesDinamiques[prop][1]
        +zoomActual._southWest.lng+'&x2='
        +zoomActual._northEast.lng+'&y1='
        +zoomActual._southWest.lat+'&y2='
        +zoomActual._northEast.lat+''); //service that return a list of points

        addAreaLayer(prop);//crating the new marker clusters according to the bounding box

            }   
        }
    }
}

    map.on('moveend', function() {
        var zoomActual = map.getBounds();
        cargarMegaCapes(zoomActual);

    });
```

Services example (JSON):

```
e {_layers: {…}, _initHooksCalled: true}
_layers:
10054: e
options: {icon: e, title: "", alt: "", clickable: true, draggable: false, …}
_latlng: o.LatLng {lat: 41.5437192894942, lng: 2.44910020452627}
_initHooksCalled: true
properties: undefined
feature: {properties: {…}}
_leaflet_id: 10054
_leaflet_events: {click_idx: {…}, click_idx_len: 1, dblclick_idx: {…}, dblclick_idx_len: 1, mouseover_idx: {…}, …}
__proto__: o.Class
10056: e
options: {icon: e, title: "", alt: "", clickable: true, draggable: false, …}
_latlng: o.LatLng {lat: 41.541313548773, lng: 2.44995964811972}
_initHooksCalled: true
properties: undefined
feature: {properties: {…}}
_leaflet_id: 10056
_leaflet_events: {click_idx: {…}, click_idx_len: 1, dblclick_idx: {…}, dblclick_idx_len: 1, mouseover_idx: {…}, …}
__proto__: o.Class
```

Methods i use to add and remove layers and clusters:

```
function addAreaLayer(prop) {
        console.log("AFEGINT CLUSTERS "+ prop);

        active_area_list[prop]=baseLayers[prop];
        markers.addLayer(baseLayers[prop]);

        map.addLayer(markers);
        refreshActive();

};

function removeAreaLayer(prop) {
    if(map.hasLayer(baseLayers[prop])||active_area_list.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
        console.log("ELIMINANT CLUSTERS");

        delete active_area_list[prop];
        markers.removeLayer(baseLayers[prop]);

        map.removeLayer(markers);
        refreshActive();
    }
};
```

The markers doesn't show on the map, but if i activate the layer on map, the loaded clusters shows on map, but not dinamically by changing the bounds. Can you help me with an example or what you think is may be the solution?

Thanks very much

Comment: Website where im working as an example of the problem:  
 https://serveisweb.mataro.cat/visorSIG/images/RecursosVisor/SSIT/minisite/leaflet/MARC/visor/?perfil=patrimoni_arquitectonic

Comment: Your website is not working `Uncaught ReferenceError: Servei_capa_base_VERD is not defined at capes.js:966`